# Can I know jdwp transport port from inside JVM?

Tags: java, remote-debugging, jdwp

I am starting java with the following arguments:
`-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=0,server=y,suspend=n`
 and I get the following output:
`Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 59183`

Is it possible to find the port from inside the same JVM, without reading standard output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745065/identify-java-jdwp-debugger-assigned-ephemeral-port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you setting the port to 0? Typically you would use the address parameter to set the port to whatever you want.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jpda/conninv.html

Comment: I want it to get a free port so it will not fail. I will connect later to that port.

Comment: @ohadshai -- Where is it documented that using 0 for port will cause it to use an open port?

Comment: I don't know if it's documented, but you can see the result in the question. this is a normal behavior when binding a port.

Comment: I see the convention is documented elsewhere even though it is not documented as part of the runjdwp or agentilb stuff: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket%28int%29

Answer (score 1):

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Properties;

@Slf4j
public class RuntimeDebugger {

    static private int jdwpListenerPort;

    static public int getJdwpListenerPort() {
        if(jdwpListenerPort == 0) {
            jdwpListenerPort = readJdwpListenerPort();
        }
        return jdwpListenerPort;
    }

    static private int readJdwpListenerPort() {
        String listenerAddress = null;
        try {
            Class<?> theClass = Class.forName("sun.misc.VMSupport");
            Method m = theClass.getMethod("getAgentProperties");
            Properties p = (Properties) m.invoke(null);
            listenerAddress = p.getProperty("sun.jdwp.listenerAddress");
            if (listenerAddress != null) {
                listenerAddress = StringUtils.substringAfter(listenerAddress, ":");
                return Integer.parseInt(listenerAddress);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Failed to read sun.jdwp.listenerAddress, ignore");
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```